# How increase Serial in /etc/bind file with jinja2

Tags: php, linux, ansible, jinja2

I need to increase the serial number in a bind file under the path: /etc/bind/example.com with **jinja2**.

Example from this:

```
$TTL    86400
@       3600    IN SOA  example.server.com. hostmaster.example.it. (
                     2019290603         ; Serial
////////////////////
```

I want this:

```
    2019290604         ; Serial
```

or

```
    2019290700         ; Serial
```

I need jinja2 because i'll automatize it with Ansible.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

The task below does the job.

```
  vars:
    next_serial: '2019290604'
  tasks:
    - lineinfile:
        path: /etc/bind/example.com
        regexp: '(?!.*{{ next_serial }}.*)^(\s*)(\s\d*)(\s*;\s*Serial.*)$'
        line: '\1 {{ next_serial }}\3'
        backrefs: yes
```

- The *regexp* first looks ahead and matches the line only if *next_serial* is not present. This makes the task idempotent.
- The group matching the number (\s\d*) takes one space intentionally and makes the first group one space shorter. The "line: '\1 {{ ..." adds the space back by separating first group \1 and expansion of the variable {{ next_serial }}. For some reason '\1{{ next_serial }}\3' does not work as expected.

Comment: Thank you for answer but i need the code in jinja2 template. And I must first read the current serial value, and then change it.